# How to clear thumbnails from a FineUploader Gallery dropzone

Tags: reactjs, fine-uploader

I'm using [react-fine-uploader](https://github.com/FineUploader/react-fine-uploader) in a project that allows users to send files to other users. I have `auto-upload` disabled and I'm using the `Gallery` component with thumbnails. Once a user has selected the files he wants to send he clicks a `Send` button which calls `uploadStoredFiles()`.

Once all the files have been uploaded and a success message was displayed I want to clear the dropzone so the user can start over and send more files somewhere else.

I can't figure out how to do that. FineUploader has a [reset()](https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#reset) method that seems to reset the internal state but the thumbnails remain in the dropzone. They are rendered as `<li>`s in a `<ul>` so I could just delete those from the DOM but this being a react app that seems wrong.

Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

this should work even out of scope:

```
Dropzone.forElement("#idOfDropzone").removeAllFiles(true);
```